# Sql sort out "viral" topics (new topics that are most read)

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb

I have the code below that works fine. But I want to add an sql query to this function that sorts out "new topics that are most read/viewed".

As you can see there are already an query for sorting out most viewed topic - "sql_views" and I want to copy and alter that query so that it only search within in the 100 latest topics(id). That could be a new query "sql_newview" or similiar.

Im stuck with this but I guess it pretty simple for a query-guru so Im hoping for help here!

E.g: Find 100 last entries in TOPICS_TABLE and sort out these with t.topic_views DESC.

```
$sql_main = "SELECT  t.*, MAX(p.post_id) AS last_post
                FROM " . POSTS_TABLE . " AS p, " . TOPICS_TABLE . " AS t
                WHERE {available_forums_in_set}
                    AND p.topic_id = t.topic_id AND p.forum_id = t.forum_id
                GROUP BY p.topic_id";
$sql_tt_avails = array(
    'sql_topics'    => array(
        'sql'   =>  "{$sql_main}
                    ORDER BY t.topic_time DESC",
        'field' =>  't.forum_id',
        ),
    'sql_replies'   => array(
        'sql'   =>  "{$sql_main}
                    ORDER BY t.topic_replies DESC, t.topic_time DESC",
        'field' =>  't.forum_id',
        ),
    'sql_views'     => array(
        'sql'   =>  "{$sql_main}
                    ORDER BY t.topic_views DESC, t.topic_time DESC",
        'field' =>  't.forum_id',
        ),
    'sql_posts'     => array(
        'sql'   =>  "{$sql_main}
                    ORDER BY t.topic_last_post_time DESC",
        'field' =>  't.forum_id',
        ),
);
```

Edit: Here are the full (working) queries, first of, "most viewed/read topics"

```
SELECT t.*, MAX(p.post_id) AS last_post FROM phpbb_posts AS p, phpbb_topics AS t WHERE t.forum_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125) AND p.topic_id = t.topic_id AND p.forum_id = t.forum_id GROUP BY p.topic_id ORDER BY t.topic_views DESC, t.topic_time DESC LIMIT 5
```

And here are the query for "newest topics"

```
SELECT t.*, MAX(p.post_id) AS last_post FROM phpbb_posts AS p, phpbb_topics AS t WHERE t.forum_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125) AND p.topic_id = t.topic_id AND p.forum_id = t.forum_id GROUP BY p.topic_id ORDER BY t.topic_time DESC LIMIT 5
```

I´ve tried several edits but cant get "sql_views" to sort "most viewed topics" from the 100 latest topics.

Comment: Can you add the create table statements for your tables?

Comment: Hi, yes its standard phpbb tables: https://wiki.phpbb.com/Table.phpbb_topics and https://wiki.phpbb.com/Table.phpbb_posts

Answer (score 0):

SQL has a limit clause eg `SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE {condition} LIMIT 100`

Comment: Thank you Peter. I know the limit clause, but Im stuck with the fact that "sql_topics" above sorts out the newest topics now. "sql_views" sorts out the most viewed of all topics. I just cant figure out how to put them together to sort out the 100 latests topics order by views desc.